# Mutithreading & file reading

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to create application in which there are two thread One thread read char data another thread print it to console I have following code to interThreadCommunication (Assuming file has data like s t a c k o v e r f l o w) I am generating ouput as following :

```
From echo int  115 char value s
From echo int  116 char value t
From echo int  97 char value a
From echo int  99 char value c
From echo int  107 char value k
From echo int  111 char value o
From echo int  118 char value v
From echo int  101 char value e
From echo int  114 char value r
From echo int  102 char value f
From echo int  108 char value l
From echo int  111 char value o
From echo int  119 char value w
From echo int  10 char value
```

code :

```
import java.io.*;
class store
{
    int  i;
    public int get()
    {
        return i;
    }
    public void set(int i)
    {
        this.i=i;
    }
}
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        store s=new store();
        Thread th=new Thread(new read(s));
        Thread pr=new Thread(new echo(s));
        th.start();
        pr.start();             
    }   
}
class echo implements Runnable
{
    store st;
    public echo(store s)
    {
        st=s;
    }
    public void run()
    {       
        while(true)
        {
            int t=st.get();         
            if(t==-1)
                break;              
            if(t!=32)
            {
System.out.println("From echo int  "+t+" char value "+(char)st.get());  
            }
            st.set(0);
            try
            {
                //Thread.sleep(200);
                while(true)
                {
                    this.wait();
                    if(st.get()!=0)
                        break;

                }
            }
            catch(Exception r)
            {
            }
        }
    }   
}
class read implements Runnable
{
    FileReader fr=null;
    int r;
    store st;
    public read(store s)
    {
        st=s;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            fr=new FileReader("data.txt");
            while(true)
            {
                int r=fr.read();
                st.set(r);
                while(st.get()==0)
                {                   
                    this.wait();
                }   
                if(r==-1)
                    break;              
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                }
                catch(Exception re)
                {
                }
            }   
            st.set(-1);         
        }   
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {   
                fr.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();    
            }
        }               
    }
}
```

If I remove sleep() method from both of class read & echo then I am getting

```
From echo int  0 char value 
From echo int  0 char value 
From echo int  0 char value 
.
.
.
```

I am using wait() method to another thread can process. I am doing in right manner or there is any another method for **interThreadCommunication**

Comment: I'd also make `store.i` volatile here although it's probably not the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) has ready-made `BlockingQueue`s and `TransferQueue`s which are designed for exactly this. Here's an example of how to write your program using an [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(100);
        Thread th = new Thread(new Read(queue));
        Thread pr = new Thread(new Echo(queue));
        th.start();
        pr.start();
    }
}

class Read implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;

    public Read(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void run() {
        try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("data.txt")) {
            for (;;) {
                int c = fr.read();
                queue.put(c);
                if (c == -1) break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

class Echo implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;

    public Echo(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            for (;;) {
                int c = queue.take();
                if (c == -1) break;
                System.out.println("From echo int " + c + " char value " + (char)c);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After making some changes in code it is working for me..
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You are using the method wait() in a wrong way.

This method is declared in the super class `Object` and its purpose is to suspend the current thread until, and that's the important point, until another thread makes a call to the method notify() which is also declared in `Object`.

The wait-and-notify mechanism implements a kind of thread synchronization where one thread is capable of waiting for a certain condition to come true before it continues its execution.

- Take a thorough look at the API documentation of Javas class `Object`
  [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).
- Since you can only use Object.wait() and Object.Notify() within a
  guarded block I would also recommend to have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html).

And by the way I don't think your code will work during runtime since your are calling `this.wait()` while not within a guarded block. This is one declared by the `synchronized` keyword either as a block such as for example shown below:

```
synchronized (this) {

    // ...

    wait();

    // ...

}
```

Alternatively you can declare whole methods as synchronized by simply including the synchronized keyword in the methods head such as

```
public synchronized void foo () {

    // ...

    wait();

    // ...

}
```

Just a small note of advise: It is rather easy to implement a multi-threaded program by creating multiple threads and executing them but it is a non-trivial and challenging task to handle the concurrent nature of what you are creating.

Comment: I'm not sure `synchronized (this)` is correct here. The two threads have to be synchronized with respect to one another, if anything they should synchronize around `store`. It seems like most of your answer is just concurrency "cliches" rather than actually solving the OP's problem.

Comment: @millimoose you're right but I was just stating a general example on how to use wait and notify.

Comment: This is a QA site, not a "tangential lecturing" site. You're certainly not explaining, at all, how to apply `wait()` and `notify()` correctly in this case. In fact you're not explaining them at all, you just link to documentation and pointing out the caveat that they need to be inside a `synchronized` block. Which is true, but you also include a red herring in synchronizing w/r/t the wrong object.

Comment: Is it false what I am writing?

Comment: **Technically**, no. It's just not helpful to the OP, and subtly misleading. They do need to use `wait()` and `notify()` correctly, but your answer doesn't really say what that is for their specific problem. And this being concurrency, there is no general way to do so. All you're saying is how to prevent their code from crashing due to `wait()` being used outside of `synchronised`, not how to actually accomplish what they're trying to do.

Comment: ... and I thought this is not a lecturing site though it seems that you're lecturing me ;-)

Comment: Well if you're going to play with words, it's my time to move on. If I'm wrong surely someone will accept your counterarguments and upvote.

Comment: you're a distributing so many downvotes here ... what about showing us how the thing really works and providing a correct, no, a perfect answer for the OP?

Comment: 1. You don't get to tell me what to do. 2. Boann already got the answer I'd have contributed, so I upvoted his.

Answer (score -2):

This kind of question is called the "[Producer-Consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem)" and there are several ways to solve it, depending on whether you want to use semaphores, monitors, or existing bounded buffers in Java.  [This tends to be a homework question](http://cs.wellesley.edu/~ecom/lecture/ConsumerProducerRight.html), so we might need to know more about what you're trying to do before we can give you a better answer.

Comment: This should really be a comment.